# How can I add one minute to a DateTime() object in PHP?

Tags: php

I am trying to make a time interval: `$start` to `$end`. But `$start` is always ending up the same as `$end`, as if they are both getting modified.

```
$dt = new \DateTime();
$start = $dt;
$end = $dt->modify('+1 minute');
echo $start->format('i') . ' - ' . $end->format('i');
```

This just gave me

> 50 - 50

When I want

> 49 - 50

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:
I don't want to work with timestamps, only DateTime() objects.

Comment: `$start` refers to the same object as `$end`, make 2 datetime objects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Why this is happening

`$start` and `$end` both refer to the same object so when you add 1 minute to `$dt` both `$start` and `$end` will reflect the change.

## What can you do

To fix, set `$start` and `$end` to new instances of the datetime object.

```
$dt = new \DateTime();
$start = new $dt;
$end = new $dt;
$end->modify('+1 minute');
echo $start->format('i') . ' - ' . $end->format('i');
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to the already given answers would be to use

- [`DateTimeImmutable`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeimmutable.php) -  This class behaves the same as DateTime except it never modifies itself but returns a new object instead.

Example:

```
$start = new \DateTimeImmutable();
$end = $start->modify('+1 minute');
echo $start->format('i') . ' - ' . $end->format('i');
```

This would give your expected result.

Comment: Wasn't aware of `DateTimeImmutable`, that's a really tidy solution.

Answer (score 1):

You create a single DateTime object `$dt` and then use the same object as both `$start` and `$end`. You should do one of the following:

```
$dt = new \DateTime();
$start = $dt->format('i'); //Store the actual string before modifying
$dt->modify('+1 minute'); 
echo $start . ' - ' . $end->format('i');
```

Or:

```
$start = new \DateTime();
$end = new \DateTime();    
$end->modify('+1 minute'); 
echo $start->format('i') . ' - ' . $end->format('i');
```